# Failed to deploy the latest rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I install erlang(erlang-20.3.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm),the installed rabbimq(rabbitmq-server-3.7.6). When I check the node status, rabbitmqctl got the 
crush message.Have I lost something? Many appritiation!

---

```
=INFO REPORT==== 20-Jun-2018::11:11:00.813218 ===
    application: logger
    exited: {{shutdown,
                 {failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler',noproc}},
             {'Elixir.Logger.App',start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: temporary
Could not start application logger: Logger.App.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Logger.ErrorHandler
    ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
```

---

Comment: What is the output of `erl -version`?

Comment: I has the same proplem with Rabbit 3.7.6 and Erlang/OTP 21.0, I change Erlang/OTP to 20.3 then it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I just installed `rabbitmq-server` v3.7.6 and If you are running debian-based distro, makes sure you have pinned your `esl-erlang` and `erlang*` package to 20.3.x ([see here for more detail](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#apt-pinning)). Also, makes sure `/var/lib/rabbitmq` directory belongs to `rabbitmq` user and group. If not, use `chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq` to fix it.
And finally, just install one of these packages, `esl-erlang` or `erlang`.

I saw that you type `erlang-20.3.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`, but the latest version for v20.3.x branch is v20.3.6. Please check it again...

Read the rabbitmq compatibility with erlang/otp [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html). I already tested using above configuration, and it works perfectly after I typed `sudo rabbitmq-ctl status`.

If success, you may see below result.

```
Status of node rabbit@eternalbox ...
[{pid,28772},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.7.6"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.15.3"},
      {rabbit_common,
          "Modules shared by rabbitmq-server and rabbitmq-erlang-client",
          "3.7.6"},
      {ranch_proxy_protocol,"Ranch Proxy Protocol Transport","1.5.0"},
      {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.5.0"},
      {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","8.2.6"},
      {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","1.5.2"},
      {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 5.0.5","5.0.5"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4.4"},
      {crypto,"CRYPTO","4.2.2"},
      {jsx,"a streaming, evented json parsing toolkit","2.8.2"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.16"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","6.5.1"},
      {recon,"Diagnostic tools for production use","2.3.2"},
      {lager,"Erlang logging framework","3.5.1"},
      {goldrush,"Erlang event stream processor","0.1.9"},
      {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","7.1.5"},
      {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","2.1.4"},
      {syslog,"An RFC 3164 and RFC 5424 compliant logging framework.","3.4.2"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","3.1.2"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.4.5"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","5.4.3"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:128] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{connection_readers,0},
      {connection_writers,0},
      {connection_channels,0},
      {connection_other,0},
      {queue_procs,0},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,5936},
      {other_proc,19686048},
      {metrics,184824},
      {mgmt_db,0},
      {mnesia,73040},
      {other_ets,1882432},
      {binary,57352},
      {msg_index,28976},
      {code,25081646},
      {atom,1041593},
      {other_system,12953873},
      {allocated_unused,16013176},
      {reserved_unallocated,2306048},
      {strategy,rss},
      {total,[{erlang,60995720},{rss,79314944},{allocated,77008896}]}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]},
 {vm_memory_calculation_strategy,rss},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,6579339264},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,118526930944},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,924},{total_used,2},{sockets_limit,829},{sockets_used,0}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,211}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,87},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

because you are having the wrong version of the `erlang` to install it properly you need the latest erlang version `20.3` because the `21` version only works with rabbitmq version 3.7.6 beta.

To install rabbitmq and its dependency

```
sudo apt install rabbitmq-server erlang-base=1:20.3-1 erlang-syntax-tools=1:20.3-1 erlang-asn1=1:20.3-1 erlang-crypto=1:20.3-1 erlang-mnesia=1:20.3-1 erlang-runtime-tools=1:20.3-1 erlang-public-key=1:20.3-1 erlang-ssl=1:20.3-1 erlang-diameter=1:20.3-1 erlang-inets=1:20.3-1 erlang-xmerl=1:20.3-1 erlang-edoc=1:20.3-1 erlang-eldap=1:20.3-1 erlang-erl-docgen=1:20.3-1 erlang-eunit=1:20.3-1 erlang-ic=1:20.3-1 erlang-inviso=1:20.3-1 erlang-odbc=1:20.3-1 erlang-snmp=1:20.3-1 erlang-os-mon=1:20.3-1 erlang-parsetools=1:20.3-1 erlang-percept=1:20.3-1 erlang-ssh=1:20.3-1 erlang-tools=1:20.3-1 erlang-nox=1:20.3-1
```

Comment: Why the hell is nobody limiting the erlang version in the dependencies of the rabbitmq 3.6 package then? This just broke my cluster setup. Thank you very much for the tip, @zabusa